# pushwoosh plugin for phonegap error class not found

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, pushwoosh

Hello am creating an app that displays traffic feeds, in addition to it i want to be able to serve notifications to peeps who have installed this app, am trying to use the pushwoosh plugin for phonegap build, but i keep getting the error "class not found"
is there anyone who has encountered such problem , or knows a way to solve this issue, thanks
heres a link to my index and config files

this is my index file 
http://pastebin.com/DrT2Ti7V

my config file

http://pastebin.com/XkdKNCCt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pushwoosh.jar has not been copied or included in the app build.
Please check that it is present in "libs" folder of the Android project.

If you use Phonegap 3.0 it might helps a lot as installation of the plugin is pretty much automatic.

If using older version of the Phonegap make sure you don't skip the step 3 of the tutorial:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegapcordova-sdk-integration/

**3**. Copy Pushwoosh.jar file to the “libs” folder and add it to the classpath of the project.

I hope it helps!